# How to use EventChannel and PluginEventChannel in Flutter web plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-plugin

Trying to add events to a plugin. Android and iOS is working, but web isn't. Here is the current setup:

Flutter:

```
EventChannel eventChannel = EventChannel('foobar/events');

Stream<String> get events {
    return eventChannel
        .receiveBroadcastStream()
        .cast()
}
```

Web plugin:

```
PluginEventChannel eventChannel = PluginEventChannel('foobar/events');
StreamController<String> controller = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
eventChannel.setController(controller);

controller.add('event');
```

'event' is not visible in Flutter side when listening events stream. Most likely misusing `PluginEventChannel`, but how it should be used?